# After npm run build, Vuetify ui style almost everything broken

Tags: webpack, vuetify.js

vuetify.js

```
import "material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css";
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from "vuetify/lib";
Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: "md"
  }
});
```

main.js

```
...
new Vue({
  i18n,
  router,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

vue.config.js

```
const BundleTracker = require("webpack-bundle-tracker");
const VuetifyLoaderPlugin = require('vuetify-loader/lib/plugin')

module.exports = {
  publicPath: "static/",
  outputDir: "./dist/",

  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.module
    .rule('vue')
    .use('vuetify-loader')
    .loader('vuetify-loader')
    .tap(options => {
        console.log(options); // undefined
        return options
    })
    config.resolve.extensions.add('.ts');
    config
      .plugin("BundleTracker")
      .use(BundleTracker, [{ filename: "./webpack-stats.json" }]);

    config.output.filename("bundle.js");

    config.optimization.splitChunks(false);

    config.resolve.alias.set("__STATIC__", "static");

    config.devServer
      // the first 3 lines of the following code have been added to the configuration
      // .public("http://125.183.143.159:8080")
      // .host("localhost")
      .public('http://127.0.0.1:8080')
      .host('127.0.0.1')
      .port(8080)
      .hotOnly(true)
      .watchOptions({ poll: 1000 })
      .https(false)
      .disableHostCheck(true)
      .headers({ "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": ["*"] });
  },
  transpileDependencies: ["vuetify"],
  lintOnSave: false,

  // uncomment before executing 'npm run build'
  css: {
      extract: {
        filename: 'bundle.css',
        chunkFilename: '[id].[chunkhash].css',
      }
  }
};
```

I got broken ui.
I dont know why style not applied after npm run build.
I run `python manage.py collectstatic` And there is no error with response.
[image: Response is OK]

But the problem is I guess css doesn't include all style tags.
For example, I was trying to find primary style for btn color.
But there is not code of that style.

I guess that's not relative with custom style.
Because almost every styles don't work properly.
Maybe tree shaking has some problem.

[image: As you can see, there is no style]

npm run build log is here

```
 DONE  Build complete. The dist directory is ready to be deployed.
 INFO  Check out deployment instructions at https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html

(djangovenv) PS C:\Users\Administrator\project\onepaper\frontend> npm run build

> frontend@0.1.0 build C:\Users\Administrator\project\onepaper\frontend
> vue-cli-service build


\  Building for production...Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
npx browserslist@latest --update-db
-  Building for production...

 WARNING  Compiled with 2 warnings                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   2:09:18 ├F10: PM┤
 warning 

asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets:
  img/do.88a82fcc.svg (443 KiB)
  img/do.704fd2a9.svg (456 KiB)
  bundle.css (459 KiB)
  bundle.js (430 KiB)
  js/chunk-129d8e9c.688c9edd.js (319 KiB)
  js/chunk-7b741fe2.93e1653f.js (346 KiB)
  js/chunk-88bc60dc.48894185.js (439 KiB)

 warning 

entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
Entrypoints:
  app (889 KiB)
      bundle.css
      bundle.js


  File                                            Size                                                                                                                             Gzipped

  dist\js\chunk-88bc60dc.48894185.js              439.24 KiB                                                                                                                       101.59 KiB
  dist\bundle.js                                  430.30 KiB                                                                                                                       137.16 KiB
  dist\js\chunk-7b741fe2.93e1653f.js              346.20 KiB                                                                                                                       83.70 KiB
  dist\js\chunk-129d8e9c.688c9edd.js              318.80 KiB                                                                                                                       70.60 KiB
  dist\js\chunk-9dd40366.75afaed9.js              91.64 KiB                                                                                                                        23.57 KiB
  dist\js\chunk-7bf7d6c6.c494a07d.js              86.21 KiB                                                                                                                        22.43 KiB
  dist\js\chunk-2b56d110.d1eb2860.js              50.95 KiB                                                                                                                        14.80 KiB
  dist\js\chunk-421ea5c0.84a6cf97.js              49.75 KiB                                                                                                                        15.26 KiB
  dist\js\chunk-579f7a04.941fd13f.js              47.44 KiB                                                                                                                        13.35 KiB
  dist\js\chunk-deddd822.4656d00f.js              17.56 KiB                                                                                                                        5.66 KiB
  dist\js\chunk-371f0aa5.95423761.js              13.89 KiB                                                                                                                        4.88 KiB
  dist\bundle.css                                 458.95 KiB                                                                                                                       61.26 KiB
  dist\chunk-88bc60dc.685122b2a5999d0f5608.css    87.02 KiB                                                                                                                        12.07 KiB
  dist\chunk-7b741fe2.850bc4a677d48892ff19.css    72.83 KiB                                                                                                                        10.02 KiB
  dist\chunk-129d8e9c.680d2c1c751564c3afd4.css    49.54 KiB                                                                                                                        6.58 KiB
  dist\chunk-9dd40366.c83c9f177588e6dd2b74.css    33.68 KiB                                                                                                                        5.13 KiB
  dist\chunk-7bf7d6c6.ea5a9a7d5e2a3a016c16.css    32.47 KiB                                                                                                                        4.88 KiB
  dist\chunk-2b56d110.949136521d3177d989e2.css    21.89 KiB                                                                                                                        3.62 KiB
  dist\chunk-579f7a04.b9f26f0bd2db79f122d5.css    18.58 KiB                                                                                                                        3.04 KiB
  dist\chunk-421ea5c0.1a111444deb64b94ae61.css    17.54 KiB                                                                                                                        2.82 KiB
  dist\chunk-371f0aa5.ced9d8a13720477102c2.css    16.00 KiB                                                                                                                        2.50 KiB
  dist\chunk-deddd822.07950a216d512db261ae.css    16.00 KiB                                                                                                                        2.50 KiB
```

When I run it in `npm run serve` All style is OK.
How can I solve this problem? Please help.

Comment: I almost figure out what the problem is bundle css is not included, just chunk css file only included.. I dont know why.

Comment: index.html
The problem is I didn't add ```rel="stylesheet"``` attribute in link tag for style.
Now it works correctly.